# Can I have both iCloud-synced and local-only Safari bookmarks?

Tags: safari, icloud

Can I have some Safari bookmarks synced via iCloud to other computers and at the same time have some that are just local to my computer? If so, what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, iCloud Safari Bookmark Sync is an "all or nothing" venture. There is no way to select or de-select bookmarks or groups of bookmarks to be synced or ignored by iCloud.